# Cross-browser solution to keep Floating css bullets positioned relative to a fluid Div?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, position, css-float, fluid-layout

I have a set of css bullets that come along with the Orbit javascript slider by Zurb Foundation.  The bullets have a float:left that is necessary so that they line up horizontally when new slides are introduced.  Removing the float stacks them vertically....

I need to position the bullets "to the pixel" vertically on my page sadly, and I've had trouble with various browsers, having to use browser-specific css.  I turned to jqueryUI to position my bullets based on the Div above it, but there are a couple issues.

The bullets need to be positioned in the center below the slider...and the slider fluidly resizes with the page.  JqueryUI can position the bullets on page load, but on resize the positioning gets screwed up due to the float on the bullets...

Just wondering if anybody can think of a solution off the top of their head...I've been stumped for a while lol.  Thanks for any help in advance!

I created a basic jsfiddle with 2 divs that should demonstrate the situation.  http://jsfiddle.net/KRTYd/2/

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="http://www.hdwallpaperspot.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/nature-background-wallpaper.jpg" style="width:100%;"></img>
</div>
<div id="bullets"></div>
```

Specifically the html is this:

```
<ul data-orbit>
  <li>
    <img src="../img/demos/demo1.jpg" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="../img/demos/demo2.jpg" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="../img/demos/demo3.jpg" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the bullet css looks like this:

```
.orbit-bullets {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
 }
  .orbit-bullets li {
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 6px;
    border: solid 3px #666666;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1000px;
    border-radius: 1000px; }
```

And due to multiple slides indicated in the html, multiple css bullets are generated by javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.orbit_bullets{
    text-align:center;
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.orbit_bullets li {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
    border: solid 3px #666666;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1000px;
    border-radius: 1000px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This format seems to be working, I just added a `position:relative;left:__%;` to the `.orbit-bullets li{}` because the bullets weren't visible and off to the left.  They seem to be positioning well now though with the float gone.  :D I'd give rep If I could but I'm a SOF noob haha @GCyrillus

Comment: Glad to help! It works becasue .orbit_bullets{text-align:center} centers all li elements inside it and .orbit_bullets li {display:inline-block;} makes them an inline element.

Answer (score 1):

Looks familiar to me, i think i already answered this question.

Anyway, `#bullet {margin:auto;}` instead flotting will do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/yAgdT/

But i do not believe that will do it for the slider once you have many img to slide.
`#bullets` should become parents of bullets 
http://jsfiddle.net/yAgdT/1/

These are supposition, since we have no idea what's gonna be sliding and what you wanna do with the bullets :) .

maybe something more usefull, on the way to become a slider maybe : http://jsfiddle.net/yAgdT/2/

Else, here's a slider i played with where i produce bullets with box-shadow. *it runs without javascript.* http://dabblet.com/gist/4323453 it's not an anser, but html structure might interest you . if you wish to relay on CSS selectors.

Comment: Looks like last time it was asked , question was deleted.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the other day I asked it under a coworker's account by accident.  Thought i'd repost because the 1st was difficult to understand as well.

Comment: The bullets are for selecting/indicating the current slide like on this page http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html.  They're generated in response to an additional <li> tag in the html.  The margin works great for the jsfiddle example, but I just can't remove the float in reality because it makes multiple bullets stack vertically as opposed to horizontally?

Comment: I edited my original post to include more specifics...margins on the child bullets are to keep them spaced next to each other

Comment: oki i just saw your update, meanwhile i did this to show you my point :) http://jsfiddle.net/yAgdT/2/

Comment: What about http://jsfiddle.net/yAgdT/1/ (missing info in beginning) and other answer wich propose similar structure but with good info at that time ? it is suppose to answer your question. :)

Comment: Yeah thanks a bunch for the help!  It seems like yours and Mansimran's suggestions are similar and it looks like that method is working for me :)